# Can't Execute a Select query Run-time error 3065

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am running the below code to run sql and display the product within the messagebox.  This works fine.  My question is if I want to display all the products at the same time so that I can copy or export the result out just like if I would run the Access Query and it would give me all the products displayed.  What can I do here?  Do I need to re-write the whole query or just change the for loop and msgbox to something else?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rcnt As Integer
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT jd.Product FROM Consumption_JobDetails 
AS jd " & _"INNER JOIN Consumption_JobRepairCentre AS jc ON jd.jobnumber = 
jc.jobnumber;")

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

For rcnt = 0 To rs.RecordCount
MsgBox (rs.Fields("Product").Value)
rs.MoveNext
Next rcnt
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906567/run-time-error-3065-cannot-execute-a-select-query/25907026

Comment: As per the link provided, should I not use the execute command?

Comment: `Execute` does not return records, and based on your `Select` statement, you are expecting it to return records. So you do not want to use `Execute` - After all, where are you telling it the object to put the records into? `Execute` does not give you that option. You need a `Recordset` object.

Comment: Why have you declared two recordset objects that are not used? Why bother with variables for table names? What do you want to happen with data? So far you incorrectly attempt a SELECT query with Execute method.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT statement is used to open a recordset object. Execute is used for action SQL (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, etc).

Don't see any need for variables for table names.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Product FROM Consumption_JobDetails AS jd " & _
         "INNER JOIN Consumption_JobRepairCentre AS jc ON jd.jobnumber = jc.jobnumber;")
```

Comment: I ran exactly this code and nothing happened,  No error but no result.  I want result of this select query to be displayed.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? That code populates the recordset called `rs` with the data from your select statement. That code does not "do anything else" - what you then do with that recordset is up to you. Your original question does not do anything other than show a message box at the end either.

Comment: If you want 'result of this select query to be displayed' then set the RecordSource of a form. Or set the RecordSource of form or report to SQL statement in design view. Or build a query object with that SQL and open that object. A recordset itself cannot display on screen. A recordset is used to manipulate data in memory and is not directly viewable.